# Unable to Config Android sdk in Mobile First Foundation 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, android-sdk-tools

I am working on hybrid Apps over IBM Mobile First Foundation on eclipse,I want to build an android app of the project, but when i configure the android SDK location and click on apply, nothing happens
Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear enough... what are you applying? where? are you getting any errors, if yes, what are they?

When using MobileFirst Studio in Eclipse, the Android project can be generated in two ways.

1. By using the Google ADT tools.

   - [Install the Eclipse plug-in](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) and re-build the project by right-clicking the *application folder* and selecting Run As > Run on MobileFirst Development Server
2. By providing the path to Android Studio.

   - First install Android Studio and then, in Eclipse, navigate to File > Preferences > MobileFirst. Provide the path to the folder containing the executable. For example in Mac OS X that would be `/Applications`.
   - Then right-click on the *Android environment folder* and select Run As > Android Studio project.

   Note: be sure not to convert the project to Gradle structure - this is currently not supported.

Comment: Okay, try pointing to the directory containing the Android Studio folder and follow the steps mentioned in (2). If it doesn't work, point to the folder containing Android Studio .exe file and follow the instructions. Mention, *exactly*, what steps you have done.

Comment: Im using Windows OS, I configured the Mobile First Foundation, I went to Windows>Preferences>MobieFirst> and the i put the android studio's address and click Apply[link](http://i.imgur.com/H1cZFTJ.jpg), nothing happened. Then like you said i try to put the address of the executable file in the field for path manually,[link](hhttp://i.imgur.com/Owv9cOp.jpg) the options for apply and Ok are not working

Comment: You are not following my instructions. Nothing is supposed to happen after providing the path to Android Studio. Read again my instructions. You need to right-click on the Android environment folder and select Run As > Android Studio project.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, I can now run the app on android studio , i will post if something wrong will hapen